# How to adjust grandparent style for only one child element and then reset back to normal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wanting `#homeContainer` to have the full width of the page. A grandparent element is controlling the width and margin.

Below is the DOM. When I uncheck `margin: 0 auto` the full width is achieved. How can I control the `.p-body-inner` code for only code associated with `#homeContainer`?

I tried adding this line of JS. It takes off the margin for `.p-body-inner` but it isn't for only `#homeContainer. It does it for the entire page and I only want it for that section then to revert back to normal.

For anyone wanting to see this, the actual site is: https://stangline.com/ewr-porta/

[image]

```js
document.querySelector('#homeContainer').closest('.p-body-inner').style.margin = '0';
```

```css
.p-body
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 1px;
  background: gray;
}
.p-body-inner
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.p-body-main
{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    min-height: 1px; // IE11 workaround - related to #139187
}
#homeContainer {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
#reset {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-body">
    <div class="p-body-inner">
    <div class="p-body-main">
      <section id="homeContainer">
      Need full width of .p-body
      </section>
      <section id="reset">
      This should be centered and inherit the margin: 0 auto again.
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add to p.body {... justify-content: space-around;} or justify-content: 'center' because you have display flex but with default "justify-content: flex-start" (from left)

Comment: @Robert It didn't work. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding `margin: 0 auto` into wrong element...

And with `display: flex;` children will fill the width automatically hens you don't need specify `width: 100%`

```css
.p-body
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-height: 1px;
  background: gray;
}
.p-body-inner
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.p-body-main
{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    min-height: 1px; // IE11 workaround - related to #139187
}
#homeContainer {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
#reset {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-body">
    <div class="p-body-inner">
    <div class="p-body-main">
      <section id="homeContainer">
      Need full width of .p-body
      </section>
      <section id="reset">
      This should be centered and inherit the margin: 0 auto again.
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for submitting. For this specific case, I want to leave `.p-body-inner` and `.p-body-main` pretty much as is. The element that is "out of the norm" is `#homeContainer`. The rest of the page is templated and should have the original styling. I'm really just figuring out how I can get `#homeContainter` to be the full width and have 0 margin. Then not affect the rest of the code.

Comment: It is 0 margin right now and `.p-body-inner` and `.p-body-main` are untouched. The reason it doesn't touch outside edges, is because `.p-body-inner` has padding. It's like walls in your house, you can't magically increase volume of the room by disregarding the wall thickness.

Comment: My issue is that I cannot place `margin: 0 auto` to every other element that comes in after `#homeContainer` this is a CMS type page that will be producing dynamic content. I'm trying to adapt the code for `#homeContainer` to make it work with the existing elements. It will need `width: 100vw` or % because the `max-width: 1200` code. This is the live page if you want to take a look https://stangline.com/ewr-porta/